# How to create derive from templated class and overload constructor? C++

Tags: c++

I have templated class `vector<typename T,size S>` (I have to use this instead of `std::vector`). I would like to specify an alias which is in type of`vector<double,2>` , but I also need to count the amount of all created and all currently live objects of this. Here's fragment of my templated class:

```
template<typename T, size S>
class vector{
  private:
    T *_values;
  public:
    vector():
      _values(new T[S]){
        for(int i =0; i < S; i++)
          _values[i] = T();
    }
    ~vector(){
      delete[] _values;
    }
};
```

So I thought about creating class named `vector2D` which inherits `vector<double,2>` and with two additional static variables to count its amounts. But how to do that? How to invoke superclass constructor and destructor so that it only contains incrementation/decrementation of these two static variables? `vector2D` is going to be used often in project I have to do. Maybe there is better solution?

P.S How to pretty initialize `*_values`? I tried `*_values = { 0 }` but it didn't work (of course assuming this is going to be a table of primitive types).

Comment: Is your question really just "how to invoke the parent's class constructor in the child class"? It's a little hard to reconciliate the need for re-inventing basic libraries with not being familiar with something this basic, so I suspect I'm missing something here.

Comment: "but I also need to count the amount of all created and all currently live objects of this." Why?

Comment: These are my homework for programming course, so we invent wheel again just to see how does it works. Later we'll just use already invented solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to specify an alias which is in type of `vector<double, 2>`

Well that's simple:

```
typedef vector<double, 2> vector2D
```

> but I also need to count the amount of all created and all currently live objects of this.

That's simple as well. Here's a small example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int S>
class vec {

    public:

    vec() {
        ++obj_counter;
    }

    static int obj_counter;

};

template <typename T, int S>
int vec<T, S>::obj_counter = 0;

typedef vec<double, 2> vec2d;

int main() {

    vec<int, 1> intvec1;
    vec<int, 1> intvec12;
    vec2d doublevec2;

    std::cout << vec2d::obj_counter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this is the fact that `obj_counter` works for every type. In the above example if you type:

```
std::cout << vec<int, 1>::obj_counter << std::endl;
```

It will print `2`.